# Write array to file ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have array of brands.

And I have this code:

```
brands.each_with_index do |brand, index|
  File.open('brands.txt', 'w') { |file| file.print  "#{brand.name} - #{brand.url}" }
end
```

So I want to write **all** brands into file but as a result I get only last brand, something like this:

> Biomill - htttp://site.com/brand/biomill/dogs/

It seems like my file is being rewritten in the loop.
What do I do?

Comment: Of course your file is being rewritten in each loop. You code is doing exactly what you wrote it to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost had it!

```
File.open('brands.txt', 'w') do |file| 
  brands.each_with_index do |brand, index|
    file.print "#{brand.name} - #{brand.url}" 
  end
end
```

Comment: I've found this 2 minutes ago but thanks! I can accept an answer in 10 minutes.